# pandas.plot doesn't show any figure on MacBook

Tags: python, macos, pandas, matplotlib

I make jupyter notebook file and edit it on Windows/Mac PC.

by importing needed library at first,

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and call them by

```
dataframe.plot.hist( y=... )  
dataframe.plot.scatter( y=... )
```

in Windows PC, I can see these plot figure.
but in Mac PC, in any dataframe.plot code, I see error code below.

```
>ImportError      Traceback (most recent call last)  
> ＜ipython-input-18-8044f54f9ad1＞ in ＜module＞  
> ...  
>/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in \__call\__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)  
>   2939                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,  
>   2940                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,  
> -> 2941                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)  
>   2942     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__  
>   2943  
> ...  
> ...  
> ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting.
```

I already install pandas/matplotlib via `pip3 install`, and don't know where the problem is...

Comment: The error is that matplotlib cannot be imported. This is usually the case if it's not installed (in the environment where you run the code). If you show the complete traceback, one may possibly have further information about the cause. Also see what `python3 -c "import matplotlib"` gives you.

Comment: I don't know why, but I solved this problem.
After executing `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools` command, and reset jupyter, figure can be shown...thank you for your advice.